# Read data from an input file into an array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, string, file-io

Question:

I need to ask an input data filename from user through console input, with a max of 100 characters. Then open the input data file for reading. Then read data from the input file (.txt) in the following format:

n

date(1) hour(1) NO2(1) PM10(1)

date(2) hour(2) NO2(2) PM10(2)

......

date(n) hour(n) NO2(n) PM10(n)

Explanation of input :
1.first line is a positive integer indicating the number of data entries n between 1 and 10000 inclusive

2.Date is in the format:dd-mm-yyyy. E.g.,03-08-2047 means 3 Aug 2047

3.Hour is an integer between 1 and 24

4.NO2 and PM10 readings are doubles. They are hourly average value of during [Hour-1] and [Hour]. A zero value means a reading is not available (N.A.)

5.Finally i can assume the input file contains proper data in the given range so no validation is needed and i need to print the number of records processed(the number of data entries) and print the number of N.A. values

My attempt:

-So i want to check whether i have stored the array of strings correctly in datafile[][], also check whether the data[][] array of integers also contain the correct content by using printf inside the while loop but what i get in the output is infinitely many "[]" symbols that i have no idea where they come from. Could someone explain this problem?

-Also I do appreciate any help to help check my arrays and any other feedbacks to my overall program.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS     // to disable Microsoft VS warnings
#include <stdio.h>                  // standard i/o header file
// include also other header files you need
#include <string.h>
#define BUF 10001
#define TOT 10

int main(void) {
FILE *fptr; 
char input[101], date[BUF], datefile[BUF][TOT+1];
int N, n, i=0, record=0, na=0;
int data[BUF-1][3] = { 0 };

printf("AQI Processing Final Phase");
printf("\nInput filename: ");
fgets(input, 101, stdin);
N = (int)strlen(input);
for (i; i < N; i++) {
    if (input[i] == '\n') {
        input[i] = '\0';
        break;
    }
}
fptr = fopen(input, "r");
if (fptr == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open input file ");
    return 0;
}
fscanf(fptr, "%d", &n);

while (1) {

    if (fscanf(fptr, "%s%d%d%d", date, &data[i][0], &data[i][1], &data[i][2]) != 4)
        break;

    strcpy(datefile[i], date);

    if (data[i][1] == 0 && data[i][2] == 0)
        na += 2;
    else if (data[i][1] == 0 || data[i][2] == 0)
        na += 1;

    record++;
    i++;

    printf("%s%d%d%d", datefile[i], data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2]); // try to check the content of arrays
}

fclose(fptr);
printf("Read %d record(s) .", record);
printf("\nHit %d N.A.", na);


return 0;
}
```

oh this is my weird output of infinite symbols[image: weird output]

Comment: What happened when you ran this in a debugger?

Comment: @ChrisTurner i just uploaded my output. This happens after i add a line of code printf("%s%d%d%d", datefile[i], data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2]);

Comment: You are printing the uninitialized array contents after incrementing `i`. Move the `printf` up a few lines (before the `i++;` line).

Comment: But beware, you have failed to reset `i` to 0 after using it to remove the terminating `'\n'`.